# Stop Ordering of dataset columns while writing to CSV

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to write a dataset to CSV file but I don't want columns to be ordered in ascending order(or any order for that matter).

For eg. Table: String id; String name; String age; +300 more fields

CSV formed is of schema: age name id +300 more columns in alphabetical order

but I want the CSV of the same ordering as of Model.

I could have used `.select()` or `.selectExpr()` but there I had to mention 300+ fields.

Is there any other easier way?

Currently using:

```
dataset.toDF().coalesce(1).selectExpr("templateId","batchId", +300 more fields       ).write().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("nullValue","").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(path);
```

Comment: you could simply use `.repartition().write...`

Comment: Please add the code you currently use for saving the csv.

Comment: @Shaido-ReinstateMonica updated with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround I followed for the above question:

1. added the fields in a properties file(column.properties) under a single key 
   with fields comma-separated.
2. loaded that properties file in broadcast map.
3. used broadcast map in .selectExpr() method.

Code for loading properties file in broadcast map:

```
    public static Map<String, String> getColumnMap() {

            String propFileName = "column.properties";
            InputStream inputStream = 
            ConfigurationLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    prop.load(inputStream);
                    colMap = (Map) prop;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // handle exception
                }
            }
            return colMap;
        }

JavaSparkContext sc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());
Broadcast<Map<String, String>> broadcastProperty = sc.broadcast(propertiesMap);
```

Code for writing to CSV file:

```
dataset.toDF().coalesce(1).selectExpr(broadcastColumn.getValue().get(TemplateConstants.COLUMN).split(",")).write().format(ApplicationConstants.CSV_FORMAT).option(ApplicationConstants.NULL_VALUE, "").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(path);
```